# Micronaut POST with base64 encoded form field not getting deserialized correctly

Tags: micronaut

I am building a sample app using Micronaut 1.1.0. I have a controller method which accepts POST with the MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED. One of the form parameters is Base64 encoded.

```
  @Post(value = "/item/test", consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)
  public HttpResponse<?> handleItemPayload(@Body Map<String, String> body) {

    for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : body.entrySet()) {
      logger.atInfo().log(entry.getKey() + " : " + entry.getValue());
    }
  }
```

The logger outputs a value for the field which when I manually try to do a Base64 decode, the entry seems to be corrupted.

Is there any special setting that needs to be done to support Base64 encoded parameters (or for that matter UTF-8, from the documentation it appears that UTF-8 is the default) when using the @Body annotation?

Comment: Seems like the '+' in the base64 encoding is getting replaced with " " (i.e. space). This is the cause of corruption. Any ideas as to what could be going wrong>

Comment: If there is a `+`, then it doesn't seem like the base64 value is being encoded correctly.

Comment: @JamesKleeh thats not true. The default Java Base64 encoder also provides '+' and according to that https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64 or that https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4648.txt its part of the Base 64 Alphabet